# Can not set value to element

Tags: javascript

Im trying to set a value to element (id ctl30_txtTextBox) in javascript.

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     url: "IndexMask.aspx/AttachBarcodeFile",
     dataType: "json",
     data: params,
     success: function() {
         $("#<%= DummyPostbackButton.ClientID %>").click();
         var someOtherName = "abc";
         var element = document.getElementById("ctl30_txtTextBox");
         element.Value = someOtherName;
         alert(element.value.toString());
     },
     error: function(request, status, error) {
         alert("Error attaching barcode file.");
     }
 });
```

Im getting the element, but the value is never set.
If i set a value on the page the alert is displayed with the correct value.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: haven't you found the solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Javascript is case-sensitive, so it should be:

```
 var element = document.getElementById("ctl30_txtTextBox");
 element.value = someOtherName;
```

Comment: Sorry, Ahh Buddy I also answered the same. Don't Think I copied your answer but i had to Pass from SO security check otherwise I was first. Well, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

```
element.Value
```

that 
`v` 
is in lowercase. Javascript Value method name is `.value` method not `.Value`

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery to do it:

```
$('#ctl30_txtTextBox').val(someOtherName);
```

It should work.